# How can I check Tomcat Version on Amazon Linux Machine(AMI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am connected to one Amazon Linux Machine(Elastic Beanstalk) via SSH and I am trying to get Tomcat version.

I tried with : `yum list installed | grep tomcat` but I do not know if this is the right command, because I have updated the tomcat version via AWS console and not via terminal using yum. Is there some other way to get the Tomcat version?

Answer (score 5):

One of the way is to execute `version.sh` or `catalina.sh version` , which are normally in the Tomcat 's `bin` folder.

Or you can simply search their file path and then execute:

```
 find / -name 'catalina.sh'
```

---

Update on 20-June-2018:

Just try to install tomcat8 using Amazon Linux 2018.03 container and found that tomcat script is `/usr/sbin/tomcat8` , and the version can be checked by `/usr/sbin/tomcat8 version` :

```
bash-4.2# /usr/sbin/tomcat8 version
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
Server built:   Mar 13 2018 23:41:59 UTC
Server number:  8.5.29.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.9.93-boot2docker
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_171-b10
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: The thing is, there are no such files in the bin folder.

Comment: Ok , Just try to install tomcat8 on Amazon Linux 2018.03  and found that tomcat script is `/usr/sbin/tomcat8` . Just revise my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is shipped with a `RELEASE-NOTES` file which contains the version information (although this file was sometimes not updated).
You also can unzip `catalina.jar` and look for `Implementation-Versio`n property in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.
However, Ken's answer is probably fastest and more reliable.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. Just to add something. We can use this command in order to see the content of the MANIFEST.MF file : unzip -p catalina.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. And we have to be in /usr/share/tomcat8/lib folder and here we can do unzip. With -p we are just getting the content of a file without extract anything.